# Not able to delete the directory in php 5.6+?

Tags: php, html, php-5.6

I am trying to delete the directory folder in PHP 5.6+ but throwing the exception showing Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message ' must be a directory.

```
 <?php
 $pcode="gfhfh";
 $dir = "http://127.0.0.1/".$pcode;
 if (is_dir($dir)) { 
 $objects = scandir($dir); 
 foreach ($objects as $object) { 
   if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
     if (is_dir($dir."/".$object))
       rrmdir($dir."/".$object);
     else
       unlink($dir."/".$object); 
   } 
 }
 rmdir($dir); 
 } else {

   throw new InvalidArgumentException("$dirPath must be a directory");
 } 

?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to delete a folder through http? Shouldn't you rather delete a local folder?

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: Well, don't prefix the directory with http, but use a local folder - and you should better think about which one to delete before once again

Comment: I want to delete the "gfhfh" folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to change the path("/applications/ampps/www/")

```
<?php
$pcode="gfhfh";
$dir = "/applications/ampps/www/".$pcode;
if (is_dir($dir)) { 
$objects = scandir($dir); 
foreach ($objects as $object) { 
if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
 if (is_dir($dir."/".$object))
   rrmdir($dir."/".$object);
 else
   unlink($dir."/".$object); 
} 
}
 rmdir($dir); 
 } else {

 throw new InvalidArgumentException("$dirPath must be a directory");
 } 

?>
```